# How to hide data of uncommitted transactions from other connections?

Tags: sql, sybase, sqlanywhere

I am inserting data into multiple tables and expected all data to be invisible to others until I committed them. But in fact some other application is starting to pick up the data before I am done. I verified this by using a delay between inserts and saw the data immediately.

I read about isolation levels, but it looks like i.e. `SET TEMPORARY OPTION isolation_level = 3;` has no effect when set only on my side.

Is this a difference between Sybase and other databases, or are there just wrong settings somewhere?

I'm using Sybase SQL Anywhere 11+16.

Comment: Have a look at http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc20021_1251/html/locking/locking21.htm

Comment: Each session requests a *Isolation Level* which determines visibility of uncommitted transaction within the session. But AFAIK you can't avoid other sessions to switch to a level which allows *Dirty Reads*...

Comment: @Takarii that link is for ASE, not SQL Anywhere - but the hint to look at Locking and Isolation levels is correct.  You can also look at Explicitly locking the table with the `LOCK TABLE` command: http://dcx.sybase.com/1100/en/dbreference_en11/lock-table-statement.html

Comment: @MichaelGardner - My bad, i didnt spot that. Within that link is a list of all the different versions though, on the left scroll down to the correct version

Comment: In terms of isolation level, you are looking for the "Read_Committed" (usually level 1 in sybase) This prevents reading of rows with write locks on them

Comment: @MichaelGardner - thanks, `LOCK TABLE name IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;` works and seems acceptable in this special scenario. However, I don't really like it.

Comment: @Takarii - I don't want to modify the reading applications and hoped for a solution on my (writing) side only.

Comment: To answer the initial question, yes it is somewhat specific to SQL Anywhere to be in isolation level 0 (read uncommitted) by default...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [proper page](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.11.0.0/dbusage_en11/udtchan.html) for isolation levels in SQL Anywhere 11.0.

I think you should use `SET OPTION isolation_level=1;` on the user accessing your table (or the group PUBLIC).

Comment: So there is nothing I can do on my side only? This is not what I was looking for :(